# How to convert rows to columns and vice versa

Tags: unix

```
cat > input
0,4880,1;1,8877,1;2,LT33A,0;3,2224,1;4,4926,1;

Output should be like below
0,4880,1
1,8877,1
2,LT33A,0
3,2224,1
4,4926,1
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2):

```
tr ';' '\n' < input
```

Comment: extra newline at the end for OP's input sample

Comment: Extra semicolon in the input. GIGO.

Comment: Extra newline can be easily removed with `tr -s ';' '\n' < input`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed as:

```
sed 's/;/\n/g' file
```

Comment: extra newline at the end for OP's input sample

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "0,4880,1;1,8877,1;2,LT33A,0;3,2224,1;4,4926,1;" |awk -vRS=";" 'NF'
0,4880,1
1,8877,1
2,LT33A,0
3,2224,1
4,4926,1
```